# Start chrome with windows at background instead of foreground

Tags: google-chrome, mac

How can I start Chrome having all the launched windows be at background instead of foreground?

---

- "foreground" windows popup and steal focus
- Currently I start chrome with:

> "/applications/google chrome.app/contents/MacOS/google chrome" --user-data-dir=/foobar

Comment: Did you try using the `--headless` parameter or perhaps the `--no-startup-window` parameter and see if that give you the expected result? I don't have a Mac to test to verify so that's something I wanted to run by you in case you wanted try and confirm, etc.